# Modern books similar to Hall and Knight

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

What books could serve as a modern equivalent to classics like *Higher Algebra* by Hall and Knight and *Higher Algebra* by Barnard and Child? Basically, what would be a modern rigorous, and comprehensive book on high school algebra?